# Excel formula for static timestamp

Tags: excel-formula, timestamp

I need a static timestamp to be created when a user adds data in a sheet.

I don't want to use a worksheet change event as this will not run in SharePoint and likewise the formula below will not work if the user has not enabled iterative calculation (they won't know to do this)

```
=IF(A2<>"",IF(B2<>"",B2,NOW()),"")
```

Is there an alternative formula that does *not* require iterative calculation?

I note that MS Forms supports static timestamps, so it's surprising this much-requested functionality is so hard to establish directly in Excel!

Comment: A formula calculates, so it will change. You need VBA to lock a value

Comment: Thanks @P.b - I guess that is the nail in the coffin!